# Stored JWT Access Key in Cookie but still can't access API

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, next.js

In my nextjs react app I have this for my login page to store my cookie:

```js
axios
  .post(apiUrl, data)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    const token = response.data.access;
    Cookies.set('jwtCookie', token, { expires: 1 });
    Router.push('/');
    setShowLoading(false);
    props.history.push('/show/' + response.data._id);
  })
  .catch(error => setShowLoading(false));
```

I am successfully receiving the access key from my backend and my cookie can be seen in the Application section of Dev tools on Chrome.

However, from this point I'm a bit confused as to what to do to allow me to access the page which needs authentication. 
I have a page where I am making a get request using axios:

```js
const user = await axios
  .get(`http://localhost:8000/api/users/${username}/complete/`, { withCredentials: true })
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  });
```

How do I tell my backend that my access key is stored in a cookie called jwtCookie so that it will let me do the get request? I am using Django Rest Framework and set the permission class on this page to IsAuthenticated.

I know there is a gap in my knowledge somewhere, I was hoping someone could help me bridge that gap. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to authenticate with your API, and DRF support many. You are using token authentication, in that case you need to provide the token in the `Authorization` HTTP header.

You can specified the global axios default like this,

`axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;`

You can set it when creating an instance like this,

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api',
  headers: {'Authorization': AUTH_TOKEN}
});
```

Or after,
`instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;`

[DRF Authentication Doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)

[axios Doc](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: thank you for the advice. i ended up doing this and it worked after a lot of tinkering

Comment: Is there any tutorial / library for authentication logic between drf and next js?